# Forced Answer? How to handle artificial answer constraints

Tags: discussion

Too often, I see questions--both here and perhaps even more so on ell.se--that include some type of constraint on the answer which produces less-than-ideal or downright horrible English.

Examples:
- [Adjective describing a project/goal that is not easy to collaborate on](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226053/adjective-describing-a-project-goal-that-is-easy-to-collaborate-on)
- Questions of the form "Which is better, X or Y?"
- *(Feel free to update this list with any examples.)*

Often, the answers generated are plausible in the-world-of-definitions but are awkward or unnatural in the-world-of-real-usage.

It might be useful to employ a standard catch phrase to alert the potential problem.  Perhaps a standard comment like:

> Forced answer?

Or perhaps some other way to handle these?

Comment: @DanBron, so are you saying that it's simply not a problem? ssok if u r.  I think it's more a problem on ell.se.  But if it's just a disagreement with the solution, might be nice to discuss...

Comment: I haven't encountered a noticeable number of questions with unreasonable constraints, except for the classic [silly single-word-request](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g). I also think answerers have a lot of leeway in answering the true question as they see it, so long as they explain their reasoning up-front. But YMMV. Others will weigh in, we'll see what they have to say.

Answer (score 4):

> I see questions that include some type of constraint on the answer which produces less-than-ideal or downright horrible English. Often, the answers generated are plausible in the-world-of-definitions but are awkward or unnatural in the-world-of-real-usage.

A few thoughts:

1) Maybe that's why it's a question. Maybe the O.P. has made an effort to conjure an adjective when there isn't a good one – but sometimes there's no way to know that with certainty until *after* the question is posted, and everyone else has drawn a blank, too.

2) In my view, answers that are *plausible-but-awkward* are okay, but such answers should include a caveat or disclaimer – something along the lines of, "This words fits your needs, but..."

- "if you use it, very few people will know what you're talking about."
- "you run the risk of sounding like you've teleported from the 18th century."
- "there are probably better ways to say this, so maybe an adjective isn't the best choice here."

3) If you find an exceptionally awkward answer that *doesn't* mention any kind of disclaimer, feel free fix that by adding your own in a comment, or exercising your right to downvote.

Comment: This is my point exactly, though better said.  My only additional suggestion is to give it a name.  "Forced choice?" or some such.  That makes it easy to call out.  One person might call it out.  Others who have more time on their hands who answer, or who comment on the answer, may recognize the calling-out and provide the additional disclaimer, which is often *never given* even among multiple answerers to such a question, all of whom are blinded by the false/forced choice because it's not easily recognized.

Comment: @CoolHand - The problem with coming up with some ELU catch phrase is that its meaning could be lost on newcomers. (I can imagine a newcomer thinking, "What the heck is _forced choice_?") Perhaps it's best to just say what you want to say outright in a comment, even if it's terse; for example: _"I don't think this would be a good phrase to use in everyday speech,"_ or, _"If someone said that to me in a meeting, I'd have no idea what she was talking about,"_ or, _"This option seems kind of 'forced' to me."_